# Writing a program to make an octal pyramid and sum the last row

Tags: python, list

I'm doing a school assignment where I need to start off with an octal number, "s", then increase by an octal value continuously, "d," and make it into a pyramid with rows, "r." Then, I need to add up all the digits in the last row.

I have code below, but it's constantly malfunctioning. It only works on certain test cases, and I have them attached below along with the code. For example, it works on the test case 2, 3, 5, which should give you 36. It also works on 1, 4, and 20, which should give you 230. But it doesn't work on ones like 10, 10, 10.

What did I do wrong?

```
import decimal

def sumOfLastRow(s, d, r):
    lastnums = []
    lrow = 1
    
    f = str(s)
    b = int(f, 8)
    s = b
    
    x = 0
    stop = 2
    for x in range(r):
        
        for column in range(1, stop):
            print(oct(s), end=' ')
            s += d
        print("")
        stop += 1
    
    s -= d
    
    while (lrow <= r):
        lastnums.append(oct(s)[2:])
        s -= d
        lrow += 1
    
    lastnums = list(map(lambda ele: sum(int(sub) for sub in str(ele)), lastnums))     
    lastnums = sum(lastnums)
    print(lastnums)
    return(lastnums)
```

Comment: I think the main issue is that for test cases like 221, 2, 4, it converts the 221 to 335 right away, and then increases it, which is not what I want. I want it to be at 221 but if I write oct(221) it gives me 335. But the 221 needs to be an octal and have the octal value of 221. Can someone help me out?

Comment: what s and d you give the function are supposed to be? a string representing a octal number? because if you pass 10 as in a regular number which in python is base 10 and you're expecting it to be the octal number 10, well they aren't the same 10(octal) is 8(decimal) and 10(decimal) is 12(octal)

Comment: You don't seem to interpret `d` as octal anywhere